# How to sort by year

Tags: livecode

I have the following data in a variable myVAR (origin is an array, `itemdel` is TAB:

```
1949-1958   Jaggi, Ernst    (1917-2004)
1897-1939   Laur, Ernst Ferdinand   (1871-1964)
1939-1949   Howald, Oskar   (1897-1972)
```

I want to sort them by the first year so that I get:

```
1897-1939   Laur, Ernst Ferdinand   (1871-1964)
1939-1949   Howald, Oskar   (1897-1972)
1949-1958   Jaggi, Ernst    (1917-2004)
```

BUT I always end up with the following, no matter what I try:

```
    Howald, Oskar   (1897-1972)
    Jaggi, Ernst    (1917-2004) 
    Laur, Ernst Ferdinand   (1871-1964)
1897-1939
1939-1949
1949-1958
```

I tried various methods and itemdel and everything but this is my sort code right now:

```
set the itemdel to numtochar(45) -- this is "-" / also tried TAB and so on
sort lines of myVAR ascending by item 1 of each
```

Can you spot the mistake?

Answer (score 1):

I just figured it out, there was a rogue `LF` at the end of the first year range that was put into the array initially and then read from there again thus mixing my order when I sorted myVAR.

This works now:

```
set the itemdel to numtochar(45)
sort lines of tArraySortedVariable ascending
```